# Pass an argument to a yaml configuration file

Tags: ros, yaml, ros-kinetic, roslauch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a configuration file that I am loading in my launch file using rosparam,

`rosparam command="load" file="$(find my_pkg)/config/analyzer.yaml"`

I want to pass namespace (an arg) `arg name="name_space" value="my_robot"` into that yaml file when loading it so I don't have to hardcode it within yaml. Any suggestions on how to do it or if it's possible?

**EDIT:**
Following is part of my analyzer.yaml,

```
analyzers:
  robot:
    type: diagnostic_aggregator/AnalyzerGroup
    path: robot
    analyzers:
      power:
        type: diagnostic_aggregator/GenericAnalyzer
        path: Power
        remove_prefix: namespace/diagnostics
        timeout: 5
        expected:
          - "namespace/diagnostics: Voltage"
          - "namespace/diagnostics: IMU"
          - "namespace/diagnostics: Odom"
```

I want to read the namespace bit of this yaml file from launch file argument.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339328/pass-an-argument-to-a-yaml-configuration-file/) by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 685 on 2019-12-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-06**:\

> Pass an argument to configuration file

note: while `.yaml` files are used as configuration files in ROS, not all configuration files are `.yaml` files.

Your question is very specifically about how to do this with `.yaml` files. I would suggest to change the title of your question to reflect his.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-06**:
I modified my question, it was a bit confusing I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add `subst_value="true"` to your `rosparam` element (from [wiki/roslaunch/XML/rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam)):

> `subst_value=true|false` (optional)
>
> Allows use of [substitution args](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args) in the YAML text.

See also the example shown on the same page.

---

Edit: you really need to use `roslaunch` substitution args in the yaml, else it won't work. You could do something like this (just showing a single line as an example):

```
remove_prefix: $(arg name_space)/diagnostics
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-06**:
I looked at this before but this doesn't solve my problem, I updated my question with more details.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-06**:
It does, but you'd need to use `$(arg ...)` notation in your `.yaml` file.

You cannot replace arbitrary pieces of text. You must use substitution args if you want to do this using regular `roslaunch` support functionality.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-06**:
Ahh sorry my bad, yep it works. Thanks for your help :)